# I can't get trapezoidal shape in CSS button design

Tags: css

I need your help on button design in a project I prepared. The design looks like a trapezoidal shape, but I couldn't find the result I wanted on the internet. Thank you from now.
[image: Button design should be like this]

Comment: What CSS have you tried?

Comment: Is the image in the question what you have or what you want?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're having problems finding it because that isn't a trapezoid

You're looking for a notched corner, which is easily achieved with pseudo elements.

```css
div {
  position:relative; /* this one is new - used to contain absolute elements */
  width: 200px;
  height: 80px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  margin: -20px;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 250px #522d5b;
}
```

The above styling makes something like this:

[image: rectangle with notched corner]

Source: https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-create-fancy-corners-in-css/

I also created a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-sanne-wvrw3i?file=/index.html) for you to see how it works in action.

Comment: Keenly observed that the OP misstated the shape they were looking for :)  However, could you please include more than just the link in your answer?  That way if that link ever `404`'s this answer still retains some value.  FWIW, "link-only answers" are generally frowned upon and frequently closed.

Comment: Thanks for the callout, Alexander. I edit the answer.